# Pandas Python - How to create new columns with MultiIndex from pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, multi-index

I have created a pivot table with 2 different types of values i) Number of apples from 2017-2020, ii) Number of people from 2017-2020. I want to create additional columns to calculate iii) Apples per person from 2017-2020. How can I do so?

Current code for pivot table:

```
tdf = df.pivot_table(index="States",
                     columns="Year",
                     values=["Number of Apples","Number of People"],
                     aggfunc= lambda x: len(x.unique()),
                     margins=True)
tdf
```

---

Here is my current pivot table:

```
                Number of Apples                  Number of People
                2017    2018    2019    2020      2017    2018    2019    2020   
California        10      18      20      25         2       3       4       5
West Virginia      8      35      25      12         2       5       5       4
...
```

---

I want my pivot table to look like this, where I add additional columns to divide Number of Apples by Number of People.

```
                Number of Apples                  Number of People                  Number of Apples per Person
                2017    2018    2019    2020      2017    2018    2019    2020      2017    2018    2019    2020   
California        10      18      20      25         2       3       4       5       5       6       5       5      
West Virginia      8      35      25      12         2       5       5       4       4       7       5       3
```

---

I've tried a few things, such as:

- Creating a new column via assigning new column names, but does not work with multiple column index `tdf["Number of Apples per Person"][2017] = tdf["Number of Apples"][2017] / tdf["Number of People"][2017]`
- Tried the other assignment method `tdf.assign(tdf["Number of Apples per Person"][2017] = tdf["Enrollment ID"][2017] / tdf["Student ID"][2017])`; got this error `SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?`

Appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your dataframe before you pivot?

Comment: also for your aggfunc, use `nunique` instead

Comment: have you tried this? `df['Number of Apples'] / df['Number of people']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do here is `stack()`, do your thing, and then `unstack()`:

```
s = df.stack()
s['Number of Apples per Person'] = s['Number of Apples'] / s['Number of People']
df = s.unstack()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
              Number of Apples                Number of People                Number of Apples per Person               
                          2017 2018 2019 2020             2017 2018 2019 2020                        2017 2018 2019 2020
California                  10   18   20   25                2    3    4    5                         5.0  6.0  5.0  5.0
West Virginia                8   35   25   12                2    5    5    4                         4.0  7.0  5.0  3.0
```

One-liner:

```
df = df.stack().pipe(lambda x: x.assign(**{'Number of Apples per Person': x['Number of Apples'] / x['Number of People']})).unstack()
```